# Export SQL Data to Excel Insert into specified Sheet

Tags: sql-server-2008, excel-2010

ultimately I am trying to export data from the SQL table and insert it into a tab in the Excel sheet and then have it mailed to a group. I am not 100% set on this method of doing this but this is the only way I found online that seems to suggest it will get me what I want unfortunately I cannot find a fix for this specific issue. but every time I try it I get an error implying that the file is read only. I have checked the file and I have rights I have also rebooted the server thinking maybe it is locked in memory but still nothing. 
I have been googling all day long and have reached my breaking point on this one. It is a Windows 2008 R2 Enterprise server with SQL Server 2008.

```
EXEC sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', N'AllowInProcess', 1

EXEC sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', N'DynamicParameters', 1


 insert into OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
 'Excel 12.0;Database=D:\Template\Availability.xlsx;IMEX=1;HDR=YES','SELECT [Site ID],[Schedule Date] FROM [Quota_Points$A:J]') 
 Select [Site ID],[Schedule Date] from 
 (select [Site_ID] as 'Site ID'
      ,[Schedule_Date] AS 'Schedule Date'

       from [smb].[dbo].[JobAvailability]) a
```

Error message :

```
Error(s)
OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)" returned message "Cannot update. Database or object is read-only.".
Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 1

The OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. The provider indicates that the user did not have the permission to perform the operation.


Msg 7343, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
The OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)" could not INSERT INTO table "[Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0]".
```

Comment: I would recommend reading from the database using your preferred scripting language. Save as .csv. Email. Person opens with Excel

Comment: Is the file name and folder correct?  Verify `D:\Template\Availability.xlsx`.

Comment: It is the correct file name and directory. Just to be on the safe side I copy and pasted the directory and file name.

Comment: Saving as a CSV is what I am trying to stay away from, I have an excel file with formulas already. The purpose here is to fill the one sheet of the workbook with the raw data so that I don't have to have it emailed to me just for me to open it, copy it and paste it into another workbook. Trying to accomplish everything in one task